# My Key Press Doesn't Work in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I am having trouble finding the issue in my coding. When I go back to Unity and hit play the text-based game starts up in the "Wake Up" scene as instructed. However, the game is unresponsive to any keys pressed. The scene never changes and it stays in "Wake Up" unless I manually to the sNextHeading tab and type in a different scenes name. For example, I type in "Check Woven Basket" and that scene loads. I know all my scenes work, but they are just unresponsive to the key presses. I have re watched my lectures in school and they look identical. I must be overlooking something, and I am hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

```
Page[] aBook;

public string sPrevHeading;
public string sCurrHeading;
public string sNextHeading = "Wake Up";

void Start()
{

    BindBook();
    RenderStory();
}

void Update() //Input Keys Don't Work
{ 
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))
    {
        if (sCurrHeading == "Wake Up")
        {
            sNextHeading = "Check Woven Basket";
        }
    }
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))
    {
        if (sCurrHeading == "Wake Up")
        {
            sNextHeading = "Check Door";
        }
        else if (sCurrHeading == "Pick Up")
        {
            sNextHeading = "Drink Milk";
        }
    }
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.B))
    {
        if (sCurrHeading == "Wake Up")
        {
            sNextHeading = "Check Bowl";
        }
    }
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.P))
    {
        if (sCurrHeading == "Bowl")
        {
            sNextHeading = "Pick Up";
        }
        else if (sCurrHeading == "Pick Up")
        {
            sNextHeading = "Pour Milk";
        }
    }
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Y))
    {
        if (sCurrHeading == "Drink Milk" ||
            sCurrHeading == "Pour Milk")
        {
            sNextHeading = "Wake Up";
        }
    }
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.N))
    {
        if (sCurrHeading == "Drink Milk" ||
            sCurrHeading == "Pour Milk")
        {
            sNextHeading = "Thank You";
        }
    }

    RenderStory();
}

void RenderStory()
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sNextHeading))
    {
        for (int nPage = 0; nPage < aBook.Length; nPage++)
        {
            if (sNextHeading == aBook[nPage].Heading)
            {
                sCurrHeading = sNextHeading;
                sNextHeading = "";

                Debug.Log(aBook[nPage].Body);
            }
        }
    }
}

void BindBook()
{
    aBook = new Page[]
    {
        new Page("Wake Up", "(Wake Up)\nCheck the [W]oven Basket, [B]owl, or check the [D]oor?"),
        new Page("Check Woven Basket", "(Woven Basket)\n[X] to return to previous step."),
        new Page("Check Bowl", "(Check Bowl)\n[P]ick up bowl of mile or [X] to return."),
        new Page("Check Door", "(Check Door)\n[X] to return to previous step."),
        new Page("Pick Up", "(Pick Up)\n[P]our out the milk, [D]rink the liquid or [X] to return to previous step."),
        new Page("Pour Milk", "(Pour Milk)\nWin Play again [Y]es or [N]o?"),
        new Page("Drink Milk", "(Drink Milk)\nLose Play again [Y]es or [N]o?"),
        new Page("Thank You", "(Thank You)\nThank you for playing!")
    };

}
```

}

Comment: If you put a breakpoint on `if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))` does it get hit?

Comment: What calls `Update`?

Comment: @Richard [Unity](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html) should.

Comment: Ensure that your class derives from MonoBehaviour and is attached to a GameObject in your scene.

Comment: @IanH. When I posted the question I did forget to copy that section into the code. However, it does derive from MonoBehaviour and is properly attached.

Comment: @mjwills I put the breakpoint on the line you recommended and yes it does get hit. I can't hit continue past that point. When I hit continue after it hits the breakpoint it just hits it again.

Comment: Few reasons that i can think of, your script might not attached to a gameObject, if so gameObject might disabled. Try adding debug logs to get keys to make sure they are called, if they are called sCurrHeading seems empty in the beginning maybe thats why it is not getting called. If it is not empty in the run time, your scene names might be wrong or you did not add those scenes to build settings.

Comment: Is it possible that your keyboard settings are changed (country-settings)? Because you are saying the breakpoints do get hit, i suspect that could be the culprit.

Comment: `sCurrHeading` must be something else than exactly "Wake Up" then. Look for invisible characters like spaces or newlines. Add something like `Debug.Log(sCurrHeading);` to see what it actually is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so I have been trying all the helpful options everyone has suggested, and I found the solution to my issue. My key words I'm trying to search for didn't match what I set in the array. For example, "Bowl" vs. "Check Bowl." The heading I am checking against didn't properly match the heading I created. However, I wrote down all these possible fixes just in case I have a problem in the future. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

I think `sCurrHeading` is actually `null` when you start the game: it says so in this code snippet:

```
public string sCurrHeading;
public string sNextHeading = "Wake Up";
```

Changing it to

```
public string sCurrHeading = "Wake Up";
public string sNextHeading;
```

might help.

Because it's `null`, all those checks like `if (sCurrHeading == "Wake Up")` will fail and the `else` statements too.